# What does "Complex is better than complicated" mean?

Tags: python

In "The Zen of Python", by Tim Peters, the sentence "Complex is better than complicated" confused me. Can anyone give a more detailed explanation or an example?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

although complex and complicated sound alike, they do not mean the same in this context.

The Zen therefore says: It is okay to build very complex applications, as long as the need for it is reasonable.

To give an example:

```
counter = 0
while counter < 5:
   print counter
   counter += 1
```

The code is very easy to understand. It is not complex. However, it is complicated. You do not need to manually perform most of the steps above.

```
for i in xrange(5):
   print i
```

This code is more complex than the above example. But: knowing the documentation of  ´xrange´ you can understand it by a single glance. Many steps are hidden behind an easy-to-use-interface.

As processes grow bigger, the gap between complicated and complex gets wider and wider.

A general rule of thumb is to follow the other principles of the Zen of Python:

If it is hard to explain, it is not a good idea.

If it's easy to explain, it might be a good idea.

Answer (score 14):

Complex: Does a lot. Usually unavoidable.

Complicated: Difficult to understand.

I like this quote ([source](http://aphilosopher.wordpress.com/2007/08/16/complex-vs-complicated/)):

> A complex person is like an iPod. That
>   is to say that they are consistent,
>   straightforward and ‘user friendly’
>   while also being rather sophisticated.
>   Unlike the complicated person,
>   interacting with a complex person does
>   not require special knowledge of their
>   complicated ways-because their ways
>   are not complicated. When mistakes are
>   made, they tend to be very forgiving
>   because they understand that people
>   are imperfect. In short, they are
>   mature, sensible human beings.

and this one ([source](http://ming.tv/flemming2.php/__show_article/_a000010-001928.htm)):

> An Airbus A380 is complicated. A
>   jellyfish is complex. The Paris Metro
>   network is complicated. How people use
>   it is complex. Your skeleton is
>   complicated. You are complex. A
>   building is complicated. A city is
>   complex.

Some more articles on this:

- [Simple vs. Complicated vs. Complex vs. Chaotic](http://www.noop.nl/2008/08/simple-vs-complicated-vs-complex-vs-chaotic.html)
- [More on Complex versus Complicated](http://smartpei.typepad.com/robert_patersons_weblog/2006/11/more_on_complex.html)

Comment: Yeah, I'm with Abe on this one.  Something that is apparently telling me to make my work easy to understand is very difficult to understand.  Uh, I think.

Comment: @Malvolio Please explain to me what you are finding so difficult to understand? I think I put it quite simply.

Comment: Your quotes don't make any sense to me.  An airplane is X, but a jellyfish is Y.  Well, what does that mean?  An airplane is man-made, so it's certainly more understandable, if only because we could ask the people who made it how it's supposed to work; analyzing a jellyfish can only be done empirically.  Is that the distinction I'm supposed to be drawing?  How about a building versus a city.  That seems like a difference in scale, but almost nothing else.  Basically, I have no idea what I am supposed to learn from these juxtapositions.

Comment: @Malvolio I' agree with you that the A380 could be considered as complex, but maybe the author knows more about the specific model than we do. However, a building on its own is usually not very complex, but can be a complicated maze. A city is much more than just a large number of buildings. Everything within interacts in a complex manner: the people, the shops, the offices, etc.

Comment: An A380 is a *big honkin' plane* but basically similar to all other planes.  A city seems to me like a building in macrocosm -- it has streets instead of hallways, subways instead of elevators, and so on.  None of which (I think) has anything to with the complicated/complex question.

Comment: @Malvolio So the A380 is similar to a Cessna? I think not. There's most definitely varying levels of complexity across planes. You've just hit it yourself with the city vs building comparison. Compare that now to a single class vs a project of hundreds of classes.

Comment: The articles description could perhaps be summed up as: a complicated system takes a lot of effort to entirely understand. A complex system you wouldn't normally try to entirely work out, because it's predictable without knowing all the details. Whether that's the intended distinction in the Zen, I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

For "complicated", the difficult thing is on the surface. (You description is complicated.)

For "complex", the difficult thing is under the table. (A car is complex.)

Just as shown by EinLama's examples.

Comment: Best comment by far

Answer (score 2):

i haven't read this book.

complex is in my opinion a solution that might be not easy to understand but is writen in simple and logic code.

complicated is a solution that might be simple (or complex) but is written in code which is not easy to understand because there are no patterns or logic in it and no proper metaphors and naming.

Comment: It is not a book,  "import this",  you can see it

Comment: @flycondor thanx, now it makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

Complicated systems are highly coupled and therefore fragile.

Complex systems are made of simple parts operating together to create complex emergent behavior. While the emergent behaviors may still be a challenge, the individual parts can be isolated, studied, and debugged. Individual parts can be removed and reused.

I comment more on this topic and provide examples [on my blog](http://heatertech.blogspot.com/2014/03/simple-complex-complicated.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to Pro Python third edition:

> 

For the sake of this guideline, most situations tend to take the following view of
the two terms:
• Complex: Made up of many interconnected parts
• Complicated: So complex as to be difficult to understand
So in the face of an interface that requires a large number of things to keep track of,
it’s even more important to retain as much simplicity as possible. This can take the form
of consolidating methods onto a smaller number of objects, perhaps grouping objects
into more logical arrangements or even simply making sure to use names that make
sense without having to dig into the code to understand them.

So you as the book said, you need to make your code and file more organized and use most readable names to define variables/funtions as you can.

Actually, the best answer accepted is more likely to describe the upper rule:

Simple is better than complex.

Here is the snippet example of "Simple is better than complex." from the book:

```
if value is not None and value != "":
if value:
```

Obviously, the second line is simpler than first one and more easy to munipulate, and more likely with the best answer example code.

Answer (score 0):

**Complicated**: Need a lot of brain juice (your internal CPU) to solve. But once you solved it, you know it is right. Solving a math problem is complicated. Once done, easy for you to do it a second time. But difficult again for your friend.

**Complex**: Need a lot of intuition to solve (your accumulated experience). And once you choose a way, you cannot be sure this was the best one. Human relations are complex. Doing it again a second time will still be challenging for you. But someone following your path (reading your code...) can follow you easily.

Algorithms aim to solve complicated problems.

Machine learning aims to find answers to complex problems.

Algorithms are predictable. Deep Learning raises explainability questions on why the computer has decided to select that specific answer.

So now it is your time to answer: was your question complex or complicated?